# How can I add a calculated column based on another column in an SQL select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have fields called NoteID and VersionID in my SQL select statement. I need to include a calculated column in the select SQL query that will create a column called "Version No" in the result. Higher "Version ID" gets a higher "Version No" for the same NoteID

So, in my query

```
select NoteID, VersionID, VersionNo from Notes
```

VersionNo should be calculated on the fly.

Comment: your `VersionID` is a unique column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT NoteID, VersionID,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NoteID ORDER BY VersionID) VersionNo
  FROM Notes
```

Sample Output:

```
| NOTEID | VERSIONID | VERSIONNO |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|      1 |         1 |         1 |
|      1 |         3 |         2 |
|      1 |         5 |         3 |
|      2 |         2 |         1 |
|      2 |         6 |         2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/256f4/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
select NoteID, VersionID, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY VersionID) AS VersionNo from Notes
```

Output

```
| NOTEID | VERSIONID | VERSIONNO |
|--------|-----------|-----------|
|      1 |         1 |         1 |
|      2 |         2 |         2 |
|      3 |         3 |         3 |
|      4 |         5 |         4 |
|      5 |         6 |         5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of `NoteID` and `VersionID` columns are two numeric data types.

```
SELECT NoteID, VersionID,  (NoteID + VersionID) As VersionNo 
FROM Notes
```

Refer to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187033%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)